# Term for second language learned?

Tags: terminology

I used 'mother tongue' to describe in conversation my first language.

Are there any terms that are used formally or informally to specifically refer to someone's second language?

Comment: "L2" is another common one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Second language* is a good term.

I have often seen *target language* too to speak about the language you are currently learning, but only when you're speaking about learning the language.

Answer (score 3):

For English speakers:

- LOTE : Language other than English
- Second language. note: as stevec has listed also here
- Additional language
- Foreign language
- Language being learned
- Target language

> While often referred to as the " mother tongue / language you know / first
> language / known language " these terms may be called "source language" in
> this case.

- L2

> in this case **L2** is standing for "Language 2" or "additional language".  Where this terminology is used " mother tongue / language you know / first
> language / known language " is usually referenced by **L1**.
> This terminology is also useful if you are wishing to refer to further languages being learned/known/referred to.  ie.  "They are learning L2 through their knowledge of L3."  Where L3 is another language to L1 (first language) that they have already learned.